# Application Insights in VS2015 Cordova "Failed to send telemetry"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-application-insights, apache-cordova

I use VS2015 to develop Cordova App with Application Insights.

I follow [this article](http://www.teamfoundation.co.za/2016/02/application-insights-and-typescript/) to integrate AppInsights and put this in onDeviceReady()

```
     var snippet: any = {
            config: {
                instrumentationKey: "f2c1b11a-e3ec-4d3a-b96b-xxxxxxxx"
            }
        };
        var init = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Initialization(snippet);
        var appInsights = init.loadAppInsights();
        appInsights.trackPageView();
```

Things go well in init.loadAppInsights() but after running to **appInsights.trackPageView()**, I got the following error message:

```
AI (Internal): NONUSRACT_OnError message:"Failed to send telemetry." props:"{message:{}}"
```

I've checked that in index.html, https://dc.services.visualstudio.com is in CSP

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://*.azurewebsites.net https://dc.services.visualstudio.com http://dc.services.visualstudio.com data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

And also Domain Access in config.xml allow * URI

Can someone help me to get Cordova work with AppInsights?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue you're getting is caused by Cordova Ripple emulator failing to execute cross-domain request. Please set cross domain proxy setting to "disabled":

[image]

Alternatively you can look into [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711062/internet-not-accessible-from-ripple-emulator) to disable cross-domain requests from Ripple. When I changed I can send telemetry to AI from Cordova app without issues, just like described in the article - I did exactly as you described, this is how I placed the files.

[image]

Comment: It works in Ripple Chrome now. However, when I deploy the app in Android device, it shows the same error message again. I've researched for a while. Could you give me some hint on it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would work, since this tag is about navigation, not AJAX, but since apparently it worked for others, can you please add <allow-navigation href="*" /> as recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060534/ajax-requests-fail-after-upgrading-to-cordova-5-0-cordova-android4-0